# Background or concurrent taks in Controllers

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

I am currently programming an extension for Magento 2. I am developing an observer that is triggered when you make an action inside a controller in the admin section. 
What I do is to fetch all products and its attributes and send them to a third party service with a POST request. This upload takes some time, and it could take longer depending on the amount of products in the ecommerce. I want to know if there is any method to do this in the background, so the user doesn't have to wait until the finish of the upload. 
Also, if this isn't possible, can I make use of another method to do this more efficiently, like a concurrent upload or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any solution for your question ?

Because, I am also looking for the same.

Thanks In advance!